# Capture when all images have loaded (and do something) using KnockoutJS

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, jquery-deferred

I currently have a basic implementation that captures when all images have loaded but I'm unhappy with the code, scalability and somewhat tight coupling between the UI and viewModel.

I have an array of promises that I've declared outside of my viewModel and bindingHandler so that each have access to it. The bindingHandler will push each unresolved promise into the array and the init function will wait until the array has received all resolved promises. Once that happens a function is called that sets a uniform height for all images.

Here's the UI:

```
<ul data-bind="foreach: movies">
    <li>
        <div class="image">
            <img data-bind="imageLoad: { src: posters.Detailed, alt: title }"/>
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

The other side:

```
function ViewModel() {
    var self = this;
    self.movies = ko.observableArray([]);

    self.init = function(data) {
        self.isLoading(true);

        self.movies = ko.utils.arrayMap(data, function(item) {
            return new robot.ko.models.Movie(item);
        });

        $.when.apply($, promises).done(function () {
            robot.utils.setThumbnailHeight($('.thumbnails li'), function () {
                self.isLoading(false);
            });
        });
    };
}

ko.bindingHandlers.imageLoad = {
    init: function(element, valueAccessor) {
        var options = valueAccessor() || {};
        var promise = $.Deferred();

        var loadHandler = function() { return promise.resolve; };
        promises.push(promise);

        ko.applyBindingsToNode(element, {
            event: { load: loadHandler },
            attr: { src: options.src, alt: options.alt }
        });     
    }
}
```

In a perfect world my viewModel would just hand-off a callback to my bindingHandler but it would be dynamic, it wouldn't need to know anything about the UI and the bindingHandler would be able to figure out which element it needed to adjust. I've toyed around with the idea of some kind of deferredObservable but in the end I'm just unhappy having this in the viewModel. I've also thought about using a `data-` attribute on the parent element to know which element to actually set the height on, but that seems sloppy.

I feel like I'm missing something.

**So, I'm asking, what is a better way to accomplish this that would allow loose coupling and scalibility so that I wouldn't have to specifically tell the UI what to do (as much) and when, from my viewModel?**

Comment: _I've also thought about using a data- attribute on the parent element to know which element to actually set the height on, but that seems sloppy._ Why? IMHO it's the only correct approach.

Comment: You have access to your entire VM in the binding handler, why couldn't you do your perfect world example? It's OK to make domain-specific handlers if you want to achieve loose-coupling. Also, how come you want to wait until all images are done to set their heights?

Comment: The images are being loaded from an outside domain. They take variable amounts of time to load. Once they're all loaded I need to set one height for the surrounding parent so they are uniform. I'm playing around with just doing this in css3 instead.

Answer (score 1):

Use a custom binding at the foreach scope that deals with it. For example:

```
<ul data-bind="foreach: movies, uniformHeight: movies">
    <li>
        <div class="image">
            <img data-bind="imageLoad: { src: posters.Detailed, alt: title }"/>
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

#### Data-based approach

Make your assumptions based on the shape of the ViewModel - specifically, assuming the state of the promises reflects the actual state of the loaded images. The bindingHandler could look something like so:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.uniformHeight = {
  init: function(element, valueAccessor) {
      //assume valueAccessor contains an array of promises
      $.when.apply($, valueAccessor()()).done(function () {
            robot.utils.setThumbnailHeight($(element).find('.thumbnails li'), function () {
                self.isLoading(false);
            });
      });
  }
};
```

This might require a little more reorganization around how you're handling the logic in `robot.ko.models.Movie` but based on what you've posted, nothing drastic.

#### Resource-based approach

Requires more plumbing, but probably will end up being more reliable.

Your outer `uniformHeight` binding could register itself on the `bindingContext` and wait for child `imageLoad` bindings to each raise an event back to notify the image has been loaded; accumulate the heights as they come back and maybe debounce.

Comment: This looks very promising. Thanks Rex. I'm pretty busy with work right now so it may be a week or so until I can get around to implementing this and responding back with questions.